# Selectively disabling unchecked options in JQuery multiselect

Tags: jquery-ui, jsp, jquery, jquery-plugins

In JQuery multiselect. http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget
Can we selectively disable some of the unchecked options in the select-box upon selecting(checking the checkbox) one option.And enabling them again upon deselecting the one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this class to the options which you want to be disabled. `class="ui-multiselect-disabled "` and vice versa.

I hope you know the logic to do so :)

**EDIT:**

```
$("select").change(function () {
var str = "";
var op=$("select option:selected");
op.addClass('newclass');
str = op.text() ;
//op.css('background-color', 'red');
alert("selected"+op.attr('class'));


$("select option").each(function () {
var temp=$(this).text() ;
if(str!=temp){
    $(this).removeClass('newclass');
    alert(temp);
}
});
});
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: I used click: function(event, ui) .. i am not getting a way to fetch unchecked options .

Comment: simple logic would be, when a click event is  triggered extract the value ( using `.text()`) of the selected option tag. then loop around the complete options within dropdown and unset the the above class(if applied earlier), for all the options that dont have the selected text. let me know if you need the complete code snippet for it

Comment: thanks a lot sir, i applied your code and function is being called also , but its not disabling unchecked options.would you mind adding your code in jsfiddle, would be a great help to everybody .

Comment: @Johnn:here the working code, pls change appropriately in your code.http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/TXH2P/